# How to include sample rows with unequal values on spark version of datacompy

Tags: python, apache-spark, data-comparison

I am stating to explore spark to speed up processing and have been recently exploring spark datacompy.

The only issue I am having is that I cannot find a way to print a sample of unequal values when found. Using the non-spark version of datacompy this is just part of the standard run.

It does not appear to be an option when I review the manual on the web; has anyone else had this issue and found a solution?

Thanks in advance for any help!

*Non-spark datacompy report*

### DataComPy Comparison

### DataFrame Summary

DataFrame  Columns  Rows
0  original        5     6
1       new        4     5

### Column Summary

Number of columns in common: 4
Number of columns in original but not in new: 1
Number of columns in new but not in original: 0

### Row Summary

Matched on: acct_id
Any duplicates on match values: Yes
Absolute Tolerance: 0.0001
Relative Tolerance: 0
Number of rows in common: 5
Number of rows in original but not in new: 1
Number of rows in new but not in original: 0

Number of rows with some compared columns unequal: 5
Number of rows with all compared columns equal: 0

### Column Comparison

Number of columns compared with some values unequal: 3
Number of columns compared with all values equal: 1
Total number of values which compare unequal: 7

### Columns with Unequal Values or Types

```
   Column original dtype new dtype  # Unequal  Max Diff  # Null Diff
```

0  dollar_amt        float64   float64          1    0.0500            0
1   float_fld        float64   float64          4    0.0005            3
2        name         object    object          2    0.0000            0

### **Sample Rows with Unequal Values

```
   acct_id  dollar_amt (original)  dollar_amt (new)
```

0  10000001234                 123.45             123.4
acct_id  float_fld (original)  float_fld (new)
0  10000001234            14530.1555        14530.155
5  10000001238                   NaN          111.000
2  10000001236                   NaN            1.000
1  10000001235                1.0000              NaN
acct_id name (original)            name (new)
0  10000001234  George Maharis  George Michael Bluth
3  10000001237      Bob Loblaw         Robert Loblaw**

### Sample Rows Only in original (First 10 Columns)

strong text
acct_id  dollar_amt           name  float_fld    date_fld
4  10000001238        1.05  Lucille Bluth        NaN  2017-01-01

*Spark datacompy report*

```
****** Column Summary ******
```

Number of columns in common with matching schemas: 3
Number of columns in common with schema differences: 2
Number of columns in base but not compare: 0
Number of columns in compare but not base: 0

****** Schema Differences ******
Base Column Name  Compare Column Name     Base Dtype     Compare Dtype

---

open_dt           AM00_DATE_ACCOUNT_OPEN  date           bigint
tbal_cd           AM0B_FC_TBAL            string         double

****** Row Summary ******
Number of rows in common: 5
Number of rows in base but not compare: 0
Number of rows in compare but not base: 0
Number of duplicate rows found in base: 0
Number of duplicate rows found in compare: 0

****** Row Comparison ******
Number of rows with some columns unequal: 5
Number of rows with all columns equal: 0

****** Column Comparison ******
Number of columns compared with unexpected differences in some values: 1
Number of columns compared with all values equal but known differences found: 2
Number of columns compared with all values completely equal: 0

****** Columns with Unequal Values ******
Base Column Name  Compare Column Name     Base Dtype     Compare Dtype  # Matches  # Known Diffs  # Mismatches

---

clsd_reas_cd      AM00_STATC_CLOSED       string         string                 2              2             1
open_dt           AM00_DATE_ACCOUNT_OPEN  date           bigint                 0              5             0
tbal_cd           AM0B_FC_TBAL            string         double                 0              5             0